# resize div elements to it's children size

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar with list elements, in a nutshell, the issue I am facing is, that on the desktop version the site looks fine but when I change to a mobile (like iPhone XR), the navbar elements are pushed outside the navbar box. Ultimately I want the navbar to resize automatically as per the device width. See attached screenshot for references.

[image: on desktop]

[image: on mobile]

The relevant CSS section is the one with the class `.navbar`.

Edit: adding the HTML file, as I have CSS within HTML removing earlier adding CSS section

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
    /* html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
} */
    
    html {
      height: 100%;
      position: static;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0%;
      max-width: 100%;
      font-family: 'Poppins';
      background: #fffcf2;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: max-content;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      display: inline-flex;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0%;
      padding: 0%;
      background-color: #fffcf2;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      color: #000;
      padding-left: 1%;
      transition: .5s;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 0 15px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar ul {
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-right: 2%;
    }
    
    .navbar ul li {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      color: rgb(239, 139, 139);
    }
    /* question and answer text properties */
    
    .qna {
      margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 0%;
    }
    
    .question-text p {
      padding-left: 3%;
      padding-right: 3%;
      margin-top: 0%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      padding-bottom: 0%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .question-text h2,
    .options h2 {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 1%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      margin-top: 1%;
      margin-left: 0%;
    }
    
    .question-text ol {
      padding-top: 0%;
      margin-top: 0%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      list-style-position: inside;
      padding-left: 4%;
    }
    
    .options ul {
      margin-top: 0%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      padding-left: 3%;
      list-style-position: inside;
    }
    
    .options ul li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .options ul li p {
      display: inline;
      padding: 0%;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    
    .submit {
      margin-top: 1%;
      padding-left: 3%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .submit #submit {
      background-color: #43596f;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .submit #submit:disabled {
      background-color: #a2a3a4;
    }
    
    #incorrect-ans-text-label,
    #correct-ans-text-label {
      display: none;
      padding-left: 3%;
      margin-top: 1%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .answer-text,
    .links {
      position: relative;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .answer-text p {
      padding-right: 3%;
      padding-left: 3%;
      margin-top: 0%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      padding-bottom: 0%;
      padding-top: 0%;
    }
    
    .answer-text h2 {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 1%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      margin-top: 1%;
    }
    
    .links h3 {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 1%;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
      margin-top: 1%;
    }
    
    .links ol {
      margin-top: 0%;
      padding-left: 3%;
      list-style-position: inside;
      padding-right: 3%;
    }
    
    code {
      font-size: large;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">#RStats Question a Day</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Share</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign-Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question-text">
      <h2>Question</h2>
      <p>If the following given factor is converted to numeric vector,what would be the output?</p>
      <div class="codehilite" style="background: #263238; padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; margin: 1% 3% 1% 3%">
        <pre style="line-height: 125%;"><span></span><code><span style="color: #EEFFFF">x</span>
<span style="color: #546E7A; font-style: italic">#&gt; [1] 1    2    3    &lt;NA&gt;</span>
<span style="color: #546E7A; font-style: italic">#&gt; Levels: 1 2 3 &lt;NA&gt;</span>
<span style="color: #82AAFF">as.numeric</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">(</span><span style="color: #EEFFFF">x</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">)</span>
</code></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="options">
      <h2>Options</h2>
      <ul>

        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="`1 2 3 4`" id="1" correct-answer="True" />
          <label for="1">
                        <p><code>1 2 3 4</code></p>
                    </label>
        </li>

        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="`1 2 3`" id="2" correct-answer="False" />
          <label for="2">
                        <p><code>1 2 3</code></p>
                    </label>
        </li>

        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="`1 2 3 NA`" id="3" correct-answer="False" />
          <label for="3">
                        <p><code>1 2 3 NA</code></p>
                    </label>
        </li>

        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="Error: NA not allowed in factors" id="4" correct-answer="False" />
          <label for="4">
                        <p>Error: NA not allowed in factors</p>
                    </label>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <div class="submit">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Check Answer" id="submit" onclick="checkAnswer()" />
      </div>

      <div class="correct-answer-text">
        <p id="correct-ans-text-label">Congrats! Your answer is Correct</p>
      </div>

      <div class="incorrect-answer-text" id="incorrect-ans-text-label">
        <p>Uh-oh! Your answer is incorrect. Correct answer is: <code>1 2 3 4</code></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="answer-text">
      <h2>Answer</h2>
      <p>By default, when you are creating a factor vector, <code>NA</code> is not considered as a level. But when
        <code>exclude=NULL</code>, <code>NA</code>s are considered as a level, as given in the above example. Internally factor's levels have numerical bindings and since <code>NA</code> is also considered a level in above example, it's numerical binding
        is shown when converted to a numeric vector.
      </p>
      <div class="codehilite" style="background: #263238; padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; margin: 1% 3% 1% 3%">
        <pre style="line-height: 125%;"><span></span><code><span style="color: #EEFFFF">x</span> <span style="color: #89DDFF">=</span> <span style="color: #82AAFF">factor</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">(</span><span style="color: #82AAFF">c</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">(</span><span style="color: #F78C6C">1</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">,</span><span style="color: #F78C6C">2</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">,</span><span style="color: #F78C6C">3</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">,NA),</span> <span style="color: #EEFFFF">exclude</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">=NULL)</span>
<span style="color: #EEFFFF">x</span>
<span style="color: #546E7A; font-style: italic">#&gt; [1] 1    2    3    &lt;NA&gt;</span>
<span style="color: #546E7A; font-style: italic">#&gt; Levels: 1 2 3 &lt;NA&gt;</span>
<span style="color: #82AAFF">as.numeric</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">(</span><span style="color: #EEFFFF">x</span><span style="color: #89DDFF">)</span>
<span style="color: #546E7A; font-style: italic">#&gt; [1] 1 2 3 4</span>
</code></pre>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">


    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const options = [...document.getElementsByName('option')]
    const submit = document.getElementById('submit')

    function anySelected() {
      return options.some(x => x.checked)
    }

    options.forEach(option => {
      option.addEventListener('click', () => {
        anySelected() ? submit.removeAttribute('disabled') : submit.setAttribute('disabled', '')
      })
    })

    anySelected() ? submit.removeAttribute('disabled') : submit.setAttribute('disabled', '')

    corrAnsLabel = document.getElementById('correct-ans-text-label')
    incorrAnsLabel = document.getElementById('incorrect-ans-text-label')
    answer = document.getElementsByClassName('answer-text')[0]
    links = document.getElementsByClassName('links')[0]

    function checkAnswer() {
      if (anySelected()) {
        options.forEach(option => {
          if (option.checked) {
            if (option.getAttribute('correct-answer') == 'True') {
              corrAnsLabel.style.display = "block";
              submit.style.display = "none";
            } else {
              incorrAnsLabel.style.display = "block";
              submit.style.display = "none"
            }
          }
        })
      }
      answer.style.visibility = "visible";
      links.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Could you share your HTML too? That would help to find what's wrong with your CSS as well as your HTML structure

Comment: @NickVu, I have added the html file. Thanks for your help

Comment: your nav items are too long for the screen fit. I'm not sure what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: You must wrap your menu in a burger for phone view

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to your 'ul' in navbar
And use "@media" with mobile resolution to add "display: block" style

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
/* styles for resolution with width 650px and less */
.navbar_ul{
  display: block
}
}
```

if will just resize div it wont fit all your text

also a good solution is to put the navbar in burger for mobile device, but it's more difficult